# python requests post return plain text

Tags: python, web-scraping, character-encoding, python-requests

Like stated in the title, I'm trying to scrape a website that needs to use`post` other than the `get`.

below is the code, any help will be deeply appreciated

```
headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Accept-Language': 'en,zh;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive',
           'Content-Length': '71',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
           'Cookie':'acw_tc=65c86a0915562424980896166e8d7e63f2a68a3ce0960e074dfd8883b55f5a; __utmc=105455707; __utmz=105455707.1556243245.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ajaxkey=1F7A239ABF2F548B9A3EF4A0F6FF5FDC66906C5D06FBF3C0; __utma=105455707.894288893.1556243245.1556400728.1556404658.5; __utmt=1; __utmb=105455707.1.10.1556404658; SERVERID=8abfb74b5c7dce7c6fa0fa50eb3d63af|1556404667|1556404656',
           'Host': 'www.ipe.org.cn',
           'Origin': 'http://www.ipe.org.cn',
           'Referer': 'http://www.ipe.org.cn/GreenSupplyChain/Communication.aspx',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

url = "http://www.ipe.org.cn/data_ashx/GetAirData.ashx"
from_data = {'cmd': 'getcommunicationlist',
             'pageSize': 4,
             'pageIndex': 2,
             'industryId': 'on',
             'storyId': 0}
html = requests.get(url,
                     data=from_data,
                     headers=headers)

bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
bsobj # just a part of all the results
{isSuccess:'1',content:'%3Cul%3E%3Cli%3E%3Ctable%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cimg%20id%3D%223
```

I can successfully reach the site, but I can not understand the result returned (it's neither html/xml nor json, just text/plain, any reason why would this happen? Besides, this approach does not return all the content I can actually observe of this page, but using `selenium` can (this is slow so I'm trying to find a better solution).

My desired result If `find("div", {"class": "f26"})`) should return something like '推动一家泡沫材料对废气违规记录做出整改' (this site has an English version) other than only the HTML tag or none. 
**EDIT**:

I know that in a usual case, I can use `bs` to parse the result, but I can not use it since the returned type is simply `text/plain`, it would be great if you can try the code above.

Comment: You can use BeautifulSoup to parse text output from requests. Take a look at bs4 documentation

Comment: that I know of, it's hard to explain, will be clear if you try the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very hacky approach, but it seems to work...

From inspecting the data it seems that the server is returning the equivalent of a Python dictionary that's been converted to a string, like

```
>>> s = str({'a': 'b'})
>>> s
"{'a': 'b'}"
```

The usual way extract a dictionary from such as string is to use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), but `ast.literal_eval` is unable to evaluate the string (it fails with `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f719518c7b8>`)<sup>*</sup>.

However the stringified dictionary seems to have only two keys, "isSuccess" and "content".  Only the value for "content" is of interest, so we can extract that from the string.

```
quoted = re.sub(r'\{.*content:', '', html.text[:-1])
```

`quoted` looks like this:

```
quoted[:20]
"'%3Cul%3E%3Cli%3E%3C"
```

This looks like it contains %-encoded text.  This can be decoded using [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote):

```
unquoted = urllib.parse.unquote(quoted)
```

`unquoted` looks like

```
unquoted[:60]
'\'<ul><li><table><tr><td><img id="3383" title="%u54C1%u724CX"'
```

This looks better, but it looks as if what should be unicode-escaped character sequences have a "%" where there should be a "\".  Let's try replacing the "%"s with a backslash when there are followed by "u" and four hex characters.

```
replaced = re.sub(r'(%)(u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4})', r'\\\g<2>', unquoted)  
replaced[:60]
'\'<ul><li><table><tr><td><img id="3383" title="\\u54C1\\u724CX"'
```

This is almost right, but the doubled backslashes need to be removed.  Encoding the text as latin-1 will preserve all the bytes, then decoding with the 'unicode-escape' codec will remove the extra backslashes.

```
markup = replaced.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape')
markup[:60]
'\'<ul><li><table><tr><td><img id="3383" title="品牌X" src="http'
```

This looks good enough to pass to BeautifulSoup.

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup)
soup.find("div", {"class": "con"})
<div class="con"><img src="/public/static/images/icons/g-gas.png"/> 废气<br/>● 环境违规事项：工业废气污染源；<br/>● 潜在影响：空气质量、公众健康。</div>
```

<sup>*</sup> I'd be interested to know *why* `ast.literal_eval` couldn't parse the stringified dict.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm, you saved my weekend. Do you, by any chance, know why such returned value could happen?  It would be so nice if it returns simply HTML or JSON

Comment: @JasonGoal I don't know I'm afraid.  The amount of cleaning required to make the data acceptable makes me wonder if I missed some obvious way to consume the data.  Or maybe it could be easier to clean it up using javascript?  Anyway, enjoy - it was fun unravelling the mystery :-).

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse you should use the BeautifulSoup library, your code should look something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Accept-Language': 'en,zh;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive',
           'Content-Length': '71',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
           'Cookie':'acw_tc=65c86a0915562424980896166e8d7e63f2a68a3ce0960e074dfd8883b55f5a; __utmc=105455707; __utmz=105455707.1556243245.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ajaxkey=1F7A239ABF2F548B9A3EF4A0F6FF5FDC66906C5D06FBF3C0; __utma=105455707.894288893.1556243245.1556400728.1556404658.5; __utmt=1; __utmb=105455707.1.10.1556404658; SERVERID=8abfb74b5c7dce7c6fa0fa50eb3d63af|1556404667|1556404656',
           'Host': 'www.ipe.org.cn',
           'Origin': 'http://www.ipe.org.cn',
           'Referer': 'http://www.ipe.org.cn/GreenSupplyChain/Communication.aspx',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

url = "http://www.ipe.org.cn/data_ashx/GetAirData.ashx"
from_data = {'cmd': 'getcommunicationlist',
             'pageSize': 4,
             'pageIndex': 2,
             'industryId': 'on',
             'storyId': 0}
html = requests.get(url,
                     data=from_data,
                     headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content,"lxml")
all_div = soup.find("div", {"class": "list-recent"})
```

(If you all trying to find multiple div's make sure to use `findAll("div", {"class": "list-recent"})` instead of `find("div", {"class": "list-recent"})`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: try `"html.parser"` instead of `"lxml"`

Comment: I’m trying it, it doesn’t give me any errors, the problem is that lxml isn’t installed on your machine. Trying following this guide and then try running the code again. https://lxml.de/installation.html